# PySpark PCA: payload error session inactive

Tags: pyspark, pca

I created a spark dataframe using the VectorAssembler library, a sample out put of this:

```
|            features|
--------------------
|(2446,[2,3,4,9,12...|
|(2446,[2,4,9,12,5...|
|(2446,[335,338,34...|
|(2446,[172,208,22...|
|(2446,[2,3,4,9,53...|
--------------------
```

The data frame is not large (538045, 1) and I can run this on a standard Mac on Python.

I then apply PCA:

```
    from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA

    pca = PCA(k=20, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")

    model = pca.fit(final_df)
```

After a few minutes (less than the 60 min livy timeout) I get this error:

```
    An error was encountered:
    Invalid status code '400' from <redacted> with error payload: {"msg":"requirement     failed: Session isn't active."}
```

As this happens after less than the livy timeout I do not think it is a config issue.

The cluster I am using is also a large one:

```
    Master:Running1m5d.xlarge
    Core:Running4r3.8xlarge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the driver memory; by updating the `conf` from within the EMR notebook as so:

```
%%configure -f
{ "conf":{
          "driverMemory": "6000M"
         }
}
```

which restarts the notebook, the issue was resolved.